# Regex find all occurrences of a pattern in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a problem finding all occurences of a pattern in a string.

Check this string :

```
string msg= "=?windows-1258?B?UkU6IFRyIDogUGxhbiBkZSBjb250aW51aXTpIGQnYWN0aXZpdOkgZGVz?= =?windows-1258?B?IHNlcnZldXJzIFdlYiBHb1ZveWFnZXN=?=";
```

I want to return the 2 occurrences (in order to later decode them):

`=?windows-1258?B?UkU6IFRyIDogUGxhbiBkZSBjb250aW51aXTpIGQnYWN0aXZpdOkgZGVz?=`

and

`=?windows-1258?B?IHNlcnZldXJzIFdlYiBHb1ZveWFnZXN=?="`

With the following regex code, it returns only 1 occurrence: the full string.

```
var charSetOccurences = new Regex(@"=\?.*\?B\?.*\?=", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var charSetMatches = charSetOccurences.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in charSetMatches)
{
    charSet = match.Groups[0].Value.Replace("=?", "").Replace("?B?", "").Replace("?b?", "");
}
```

Do you know what I'm missing?

Comment: From what I can see, you can get the two occurrences by splitting the string on the space, right?

Comment: Will the characters between "windows-" and "?B?" always be digits?

Answer (score 3):

When `regexp` parser sees the `.*` character sequence, it matches everything up to the end of the string and goes back, char by char, (greedy match). So, to avoid the problem, you can use a **non-greedy match** or explicitly define the characters that can appear at a string.

```
"=\?[a-zA-Z0-9?=-]*\?B\?[a-zA-Z0-9?=-]*\?="
```

Comment: +1 might be a bit more restrictive, but that works for the given dataset

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex way:

```
string msg= "=?windows-1258?B?UkU6IFRyIDogUGxhbiBkZSBjb250aW51aXTpIGQnYWN0aXZpdOkgZGVz?= =?windows-1258?B?IHNlcnZldXJzIFdlYiBHb1ZveWFnZXN=?=";
string[] charSetOccurences = msg.Split(new string[]{ " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string s in charSetOccurences)
{
    string charSet = s.Replace("=?", "").Replace("?B?", "").Replace("?b?", "");
    Console.WriteLine(charSet);
}
```

See an [ideone](http://ideone.com/ucsECT).

And if you still want to use regex, you should make the `.*` lazy by adding a `?`. This was already mentioned by the previous users, but it seems you are not getting matches?

```
string msg= "=?windows-1258?B?UkU6IFRyIDogUGxhbiBkZSBjb250aW51aXTpIGQnYWN0aXZpdOkgZGVz?= =?windows-1258?B?IHNlcnZldXJzIFdlYiBHb1ZveWFnZXN=?=";
var charSetOccurences = new Regex(@"=\?.*?\?B\?.*?\?=", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var charSetMatches = charSetOccurences.Matches(msg);
foreach (Match match in charSetMatches)
{
    string charSet = match.Groups[0].Value.Replace("=?", "").Replace("?B?", "").Replace("?b?", "");
    Console.WriteLine(charSet);
}
```

See another [ideone](http://ideone.com/XsCifI).

The output is the same in both cases:

```
windows-1258UkU6IFRyIDogUGxhbiBkZSBjb250aW51aXTpIGQnYWN0aXZpdOkgZGVz?=
windows-1258IHNlcnZldXJzIFdlYiBHb1ZveWFnZXN=
```

**EDIT: As per update, see an all in one solution for your problem**

```
string msg= "=?windows-1258?B?UkU6IFRyIDogUGxhbiBkZSBjb250aW51aXTpIGQnYWN0aXZpdOkgZGVz?= =?windows-1258?B?IHNlcnZldXJzIFdlYiBHb1ZveWFnZXN=?=";
var charSetOccurences = new Regex(@"=\?.*?\?[BQ]\?.*?\?=", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = charSetOccurences.Matches(msg);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string[] encoding = match.Groups[0].Value.Split(new string[]{ "?" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string charSet = encoding[1];
    string encodeType = encoding[2];
    string encodedString = encoding[3];
    Console.WriteLine("Charset: " + charSet);
    Console.WriteLine("Encoding type: " + encodeType);
    Console.WriteLine("Encoded String: " + encodedString + "\n");
}
```

Returns:

```
Charset: windows-1258
Encoding type: B
Encoded String: UkU6IFRyIDogUGxhbiBkZSBjb250aW51aXTpIGQnYWN0aXZpdOkgZGVz

Charset: windows-1258
Encoding type: B
Encoded String: IHNlcnZldXJzIFdlYiBHb1ZveWFnZXN=
```

See [this](http://ideone.com/vWT1Dr).

Or since we already had the regex, we can use:

```
string msg= "=?windows-1258?B?UkU6IFRyIDogUGxhbiBkZSBjb250aW51aXTpIGQnYWN0aXZpdOkgZGVz?= =?windows-1258?B?IHNlcnZldXJzIFdlYiBHb1ZveWFnZXN=?=";
var charSetOccurences = new Regex(@"=\?(.*?)\?([BQ])\?(.*?)\?=", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = charSetOccurences.Matches(msg);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Charset: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Encoding type: " + match.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Encoded String: " + match.Groups[3].Value + "\n");
}
```

[Returns the same output](http://ideone.com/meLwOY).

Comment: When I decode an email, the first string is encoded, the second is "plain text". Example: =?Windows-1252?Q?Fr=E9d=E9ric_Gerard?= <Frederic.Gerard@company.com>. Therefore, there should be only one match, the first string that will go to the decoding function. Regex seamed to be the best candidate to extract only encoded patterns

Comment: @CloudAnywhere This encoded string will not be matched because there is no `?B?` in the middle. Did you want to match it as well? What other possibilities do you have, or it doesn't matter as long as it starts with `=?` and ends with `?=`?

Comment: I know, we are dealing with a lot of encoding. The regex I'm trying for this is @"\=\?Windows-1252\?Q\?.*\?\=" . But the problem is the same: I need to return just the patterns that are encoded to send them to the decoding function.

Comment: @CloudAnywhere, if you have more information please put it in your question, not in comments, so everyone will see it.

Comment: @CloudAnywhere You have a problem there. If you are to use one regex for each case scenario you have, you aren't doing it well...

Comment: @CloudAnywhere Also, that new regex you used should have the `.*` lazy-fied as mentioned three times now. `@"=\?Windows-1252\?Q\?.*?\?="`

Comment: Good point, I will post another question in a few minutes to generically extract the encoding from such strings. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CloudAnywhere No, edit your question instead. I wouldn't be surprised if the regex can extract the encoding at this very step itself.

Answer (score 1):

`.*` is greedy and will match everything from the first `?` to the last `?B?`.

You need to use either a non-greedy match

```
=\?.*?\?B\?.*?\?=
```

or exclude `?` from your list of characters

```
=\?[^?]*\?B\?[^?]*\?=
```

Comment: both propositions return 0 match.