# Regex extract encoding type from given strings

Tags: c#, regex

following a [recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17578724/1578604) in stackoverflow, I'm posting a new question:
I have several strings from which I want to extract the encoding type.
I'm willing to do it using regex:

Examples:

```
utf-8 quoted printable
string str = "=?utf-8?Q?=48=69=67=68=2d=45=6e=64=2d=44=65=73=69=67=6e=65=72=2d=57=61=74=63=68=2d=52=65=70=6c=69=63=61=73=2d=53=61=76=65=2d=54=48=4f=55=53=41=4e=44=53=2d=32=30=31=32=2d=4d=6f=64=65=6c=73?=";

utf-8 Base 64
string fld4 = "=?utf-8?B?VmFsw6lyaWUgTWVqc25lcm93c2tp?= <Valerie.renamed@company.com>";

Windows 1258 Base 64
 string msg2= "=?windows-1258?B?UkU6IFRyIDogUGxhbiBkZSBjb250aW51aXTpIGQnYWN0aXZpdOkgZGVz?= =?windows-1258?B?IHNlcnZldXJzIFdlYiBHb1ZveWFnZXN=?=";

iso-8859-1 Quoted printable 
string fld2 = "=?iso-8859-1?Q?Fr=E9d=E9ric_Germain?= <Frederic.Germain@company.com>";
```

etc...

In order to write a generic decoding function, we need to extract:

- the charset (utf-8, Windows1258, etc...)
- the transfert encoding type (quoted printable or base 64)
- the encoded string

Any idea how to extract the pattern between ?xxx?Q? or ?xxx?B?

Note: this can be uppercase or lowercase

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's a very simple regex. At which point are you stuck?

Comment: `string.Split` can also work for something so simple.

Comment: @Jon, +1 for realizing the **simplest** way to get the job done.

Comment: this does not return separately the 3 informations and does not deal with multiple patterns (see example 3).

Comment: @CloudAnywhere See my updated regex answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17579705/1578604) (the last piece of code) which extracts it from the previous step.

Comment: @Jerry. That's beautiful. I just saw your solution. Much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/gEJAenZUpq) that will do it for you. In short, this Regex `=\?(.*?)\?[QBqb]` will grab that encoding. But one thing to note is this, when grabbing the results, the third example you gave has two matches in it so just make sure you decide what you want to do with the second match.

Comment: You hitted the difficult point. I probably have to return a list of classes, something like that:List<Encoded> list;
    public class Encoded
    {
        string _Charset;
        string _ContentTransfertEncoding;
        string _Data;
    }

Comment: ... and perform a set of operation: 1. Get the 2 strings for example 3, and for each string get the charset,the encoding and the content.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a full working solution

```
public class Encoded
    {
        public string Charset;
        public string ContentTransfertEncoding;
        public string Data;
    }

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
     public class Decoding
{

    public Decoding()
    {

    }

    public List<Encoded> Process(string data)
    {
        List<Encoded> list = new List<Encoded>();

        var occurences = new Regex(@"=\?[a-zA-Z0-9?=-]*\?[BbQq]\?[a-zA-Z0-9?=-]*\?=", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var matches = occurences.Matches(data);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Encoded cls = new Encoded();
            cls.Data = match.Groups[0].Value;
            cls.Charset = GetCharset(cls.Data);                
            cls.ContentTransfertEncoding = GetContentTransfertEncoding(cls.Data);

            // cleanup data
            int pos = cls.Data.IndexOf("=?");
            pos = cls.Data.IndexOf("?",pos+ 2);
            cls.Data = cls.Data.Substring(pos + 3);
            cls.Data = cls.Data.Replace("?=", "");                
            list.Add(cls);
        }
        return list;            
    }

    private string GetContentTransfertEncoding(string data)
    {
        var occurences = new Regex(@"=\?(.*?)\?[QBqb]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var matches = occurences.Matches(data);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            int pos = match.Groups[0].Value.LastIndexOf('?');

            return match.Groups[0].Value.Substring(pos+1);

        }
        return data;
    }

    public string GetCharset(string data)
    {
        var occurences = new Regex(@"=\?(.*?)\?[QBqb]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var matches = occurences.Matches(data);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            string str1 = match.Groups[0].Value.Replace("=?", "");
            int pos = str1.IndexOf('?');
            str1 = str1.Substring(0, pos);
            return str1; // there should be only 1 match
        }
        return data;
    }

    public string Decodeetc...()
   }
```

Comment: why is there a -1? this is the correct answer now in production without bugs since 6 months